# Расставить знаки препинания

Tags: орфография

осенью много интересного можно увидеть в лесу идём мы по тропинке и видим ком листьев он лежит посреди дороги и дышит пригляделись это ёж листьями облепился так он к зиме готовится

Answer (score 3):

Возможны варианты. Вот  один из них:

Осенью много интересного можно увидеть в лесу.
Идём мы по тропинке и видим ком листьев. Он лежит посреди дороги и дышит! Пригляделись: это ёж листьями облепился. Так он к зиме готовится.

Comment: Очень выразительный получился текст. На этом примере видно, какое значение имею знаки препинания, позволяющие наилучшим образом передать все оттенки авторской устной речи.  Именно  такие минитексты очень удобны для учебных целей (грамматика, знаки препинания).

Comment: Всё-таки домашние задания здесь выполняют?

Comment: Нет! Видимо, София сделала исключение.